# fable websharper borelo SAFE which should I use?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to use F# to develop a chrome extension and found that there are some framework : fable, websharper, borelo and SAFE in https://fsharp.org/use/web-apps/
I don't know how to choose . Can Anyone help me to make the choice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a Chrome extensions in particular I would probably recommend Fable.

[Fable](https://fable.io/) is an F# to JavaScript compiler and should be compatible with what Chrome expects for extension development. If you want/need to use existing JS packages e.g. from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) this is probably the way to go.

[Bolero](https://fsbolero.io/) uses WebAssembly to run .Net in the browser which seems likely to introduce more compatibility issues. Though there are [examples using WebAssembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59519952/14134059). It would also, in principle, give you access to many .Net libraries to integrate with your extension.

I've not used [WebSharper](https://websharper.com/). My understanding is it also provides F# to JS compilation so it may be suitable.

[SAFE](https://safe-stack.github.io/) isn't a separate technology. It is essentially a template which combines F# + Fable in the browser and F# + .Net on the server for writing full stack apps in 100% F#.